# Strings are not equal? Testing out an md5 hashing thing I've been doing, and yes I am using .equals

Tags: java, string, hash, md5, equals

Here is the code for my class:

```
        public class Md5tester {
private String licenseMd5 = "?jZ2$??f???%?";

public Md5tester(){
    System.out.println(isLicensed());
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    new Md5tester();
}
public boolean isLicensed(){
    File f = new File("C:\\Some\\Random\\Path\\toHash.txt");
    if (!f.exists()) {
        return false;
    }
    try {
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f)));
        //get line from txt
        String line = read.readLine();
        //output what line is
        System.out.println("Line read: " + line);
        //get utf-8 bytes from line
        byte[] lineBytes = line.getBytes("UTF-8");
        //declare messagedigest for hashing
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        //hash the bytes of the line read
        String hashed = new String(md.digest(lineBytes), "UTF-8");
        System.out.println("Hashed as string: " + hashed);
        System.out.println("LicenseMd5: " + licenseMd5);
        System.out.println("Hashed as bytes: " + hashed.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        System.out.println("LicenseMd5 as bytes: " + licenseMd5.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        if (hashed.equalsIgnoreCase(licenseMd5)){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {           
        return false;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {  
        return false;
    }
} 

}
```

Here's the output I get:

> Line read: Testing
>
> Hashed as string: ?jZ2$??f???%?
>
> LicenseMd5: ?jZ2$??f???%?
>
> Hashed as bytes: [B@5fd1acd3
>
> LicenseMd5 as bytes: [B@3ea981ca
>
> false

I'm hoping someone can clear this up for me, because I have no clue what the issue is.

Comment: `getBytes()` returns `byte[]` which you can't print normally, since it will invoke the default `toString()` method of `Object`. You need `Arrays.toString(byte[])` to print the array.

Comment: `BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f)));` is a very common, but dodgy way of reading a file to a `String`. You should specify the file encoding. If you're on Java 7, use `Files.readAllLines`. Aside: think about how easy or difficult this code is to debug, the way you've handled the checked exceptions. It returns `false`, with no other indication of what happened, in the very different cases of `FileNotFoundException`, `IOException`, and `NoSuchAlgorithmException`.

Answer (score 2):

A `byte[]` returned by MD5 conversion is an arbitrary `byte[]`, therefore you cannot treat it as a valid representation of `String` in some encoding.

In particular, `?`s in `?jZ2$??f???%?` correspond to bytes that cannot be represented in your output encoding. It means that content of your `licenseMd5` is already damaged, therefore you cannot compare your MD5 hash with it.

If you want to represent your `byte[]` as `String` for further comparison, you need to choose a proper representation for arbitrary `byte[]`s. For example, you can use [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) or hex strings.

You can convert `byte[]` into hex string as follows:

```
public static String toHex(byte[] in) {
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder(in.length * 2);
    for (byte b: in) {
        out.append(String.format("%02X", (byte) b));
    }
    return out.toString();
}
```

Also note that `byte[]` uses default implementation of `toString()`. Its result (such as `[B@5fd1acd3`) is not related to the content of `byte[]`, therefore it's meaningless in your case.

Comment: Upvote. Just to make a point, I would deeply recommend [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) specifically [DigestUtils.md5Hex](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html#md5Hex(java.lang.String)) methods. It is a one liner that replaces most of the OP code. No use reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Thanks so much. The question marks did turn into readable characters when I printed them into notepad so I had just assumed it was an issue with eclipse.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly, I am writing this code as a personal project for learning purposes, not for actual efficiency. Thanks for the link to the the lib, if I ever have to md5 in the future I will be sure to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The `?` symbols in the printed representation of `hashed` aren't literal question marks, they're unprintable characters.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error when  your java file format is not UTF-8 encoding while you encode a string using UTF-8, try remove UTF-8 and the md5 will output another result, you can copy to the string and see the result true.
Another way is set the file encoding to UTF-8, the string encode also be different